# CodeIgniter Multiple Table Select Not Working

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

I am trying to check multiple databases with user given string. But SQL query always returns true. It must return false, if phone number exist in individual or corporate databases.

**Individual Users Database:**

```
| id |     name     |     phone       |     gender     |
--------------------------------------------------------
| 1  |     John     |     5551928321  |     male       |
| 2  |     Michael  |     5553270543  |     male       |
```

**Corporate Users Database:**

```
| id |     name     |     phone       |     company    |
--------------------------------------------------------
| 1  |     Megan    |     5553748594  |     demo1      |
| 2  |     Ethan    |     5559182012  |     demo2      |
```

Individual and corporate tables have same and different fields.

**PHP:**

```
$phone = '5551928321'; // $this->input->post('phone', true);
$query = $this->db->select('individual.id, corporate.id')
->where('individual.phone', $phone)
->or_where('corporate.phone', $phone)
->get('individual, corporate');

if ($query->num_rows() > 0) echo 'FALSE';
else echo 'TRUE';
```

I will be very pleased if someone light me up for see how it will be work.

Thank you so much.

Comment: I believe you can pass only one parameter in get(), so this ->get('individual, corporate'); is wrong. Have a look at the user guide for that. However I'm also not sure about the if statement you have. It always returns true because there are no rows fetched.

Comment: I've tried only $this->get('individual'); or only $this->get('corporate'); but nothing worked. Very very interesting issue and can't find any solution for 2 days :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this? (Not tested)

```
$query1 = $this->db->select('individual.id')->where('individual.phone', $phone)->get('individual');

$query2 = $this->db->select('corporate.id')->where('corporate.phone', $phone)->get('corporate'l);

if ($query1->num_rows() > 0 || $query2->num_rows() > 0){ 
     echo true;
} else {
     echo false;
}
```

Comment: Indeed, but need to do it with single query, if not possible I will use 2 queries like yours.

Comment: Does this I wrote work? I'm not sure if you can so this in a single query.. Have you tried to write the MySQL commands and create the query you want, on phpmyadmin perhaps, and check what brings you back?

Comment: I didn't test your code but it should work, problem is doing this with one query and strongly think it should be possible. I checked examples on net and they used where only once for $_POST, $_GET inputs. Here is the example: (http://bit.ly/1y4Qmh9)

Comment: this is the same thing as doing it with using (INNER) JOIN, so perhaps using $this->db->join() might help you.

Comment: I found solution with adding one more where before get. `->where('individual.id = corporate.id')`

It is working :)